# Force LINQ to Entities recognize my method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have these code(this is only example code)

```
public SomeService ()
{
    public Queryable<CarDto> GetDtos()
    {
       context.Cars.Select(c => new CarDto
       {
          CarDtoId = c.Id,
          Name = c.Name,
          Status = GetCarStatus(c)
       })
    }



    private CarStatusEnum GetCarStatus(Car car)
    {
       if(car.statusId == 2 || car.statusId == 3)
       {
          return 4;
       }
       return 5;
    }

}
```

This code throw exception(LINQ to Entities does not recognize method GetCarStatus).

I know:

- why it throws
- I can do ToList() but I need Iqueryble
- I can write method code inline without using method

But I want know  way How can I do so,that LINQ to Entities can recognize my method?

Comment: by implementing your own query provider

Comment: Did you try simple ternary operator? Like this: `Status = (car.statusId == 2 || car.statusId == 3) ? 4 : 5`

Comment: @IVAAAN123,I pointed that I can write method code inline without using method

Comment: "How can I do so,that LINQ to Entities can recognize my method?": you can't... It's plain C# code, there is no way to convert it to SQL automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if LINQ to Entities is able to convert such function to SQL query. You might need to use [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) for such cases.

Comment: Can you provide example or some tutorial,because I can find it

Answer (score 0):

Let the DTO do the conversion:

```
class CarDto
{
    ... 

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public CarStatusEnum CarStatus
    {
        get { return StatusId == 2 || StatusId == 3 
                       ? CarStatusEnum.Four
                       : CarStatusEnum.Five; }
    }
}
```

So in the query you just copy the `TypeId` value from the `Car`. And in the application you access `CarStatus`.

Note that you should return `CarStatusEnum` members, not plain integers (even when they match `CarStatusEnum` values. These *may* change in the future, which won't break your code, but will surely cause interesting bugs).